# Laptop screen zooms in and resolution changes sometimes while playing Windows games with Wine

Tags: graphics, wine, games, display-resolution

My configuration is:
core i3,
Intel HD Graphics 5500,
4GB RAM,
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I have some games like FEAR, Far Cry 1 and GTA San Andreas installed and play with Wine. Even though they sometimes work, often, the screen becomes zoomed in and black bars show on the sides of the screen.

Sometimes, only sometimes, I can access the resolution option of the games (since the game is most of the time, beyond the screen), and it shows no resolution change. Please help.

Comment: Help with what exactly? "Emulated" software is prone to limitations and glitches, all the time. If the programs change the resolution all you ca try is to adjust their resolution. Some games may oblige, most don't.

Comment: Then why does it happen only sometimes? I also want to know exactly why these glitches happen and that also only sometimes. A fix would be  great too

Comment: Glitches... I don't know specific cases because I don't deal with those specific games, or others. I only use native games (Steam).

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2878   https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=1743    https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2599  This is what you should check to know what to expect (Platinum/Gold is OK, less than that it's not, something will fail in one way or another). Make sure to choose and install the versions with the best classification and open and read the test results in case there are workaround or additional steps to improve performance.